# Command php app\console doesn't work in console

Tags: php, symfony, cmd

I have installed Symphony 2 and everything is working. But when I have tried to execute the CMD command `php app/console` to create a new bundle for my project, I got this error :

> Run command : C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\Symfony> php app/console
>
> Error : 'php' n?est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes"

Although, I have added the PHP directory to my System PATH like this : 
`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\php` (This php folder contains the php.exe)
and I tried "php -v" in my console but it doesn't work and I got the same error.

Also, I have checked If I have a folder called "app" which contains "console" in my Symfony project. I found it.

But the problem still resists. I have tried many times but in vain so really any would be appreciated.

Comment: my php version is 5.5.26 I checked calling the whole path and then php -v

Comment: Does `php.exe app/console` work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Comment: Only if I put the whole PATH to my exe it works. It means when I did that : http://hpics.li/777f278

Answer (score 1):

If the `php -v` doesn't run correctly it's clearly the PATH issue.
If you are in Windows OS you can use the Rapid Environment Editor software for work with PATH windows variable easily.

For Sure that modification is good you must reboot your OS.

You can verify your PATH with this command for find php : `echo %PATH%`

Comment: I'm sure that the entered PATH is correct. here's a sceenshot : http://hpics.li/2d2e826

Answer (score 0):

1.Did you try to Run as Administrator Cmd? Also, from what i know(but i may be wrong) Symfony 3.0 is php bin/console not php app/console. However if php -v doesn't work in your project it is rather path case.

Comment: I have tried in mode Administrateur but it doesn't work ! I use Symfony2

Comment: I am talking about version. Since december there is 3.0 version, and  php app/console does not work(it's deprecated). I had the same error, php bin/console did the job.

Comment: I know that the file console is changed in version 3.0 and me I use the version 2.5 and I checked the localtion console file and I found it under app, not under bin.